# Auto-Reply Email Google Contact Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add Auto-Reply Email to my Google Contact Form. I created a function:

```
function sendAutoReply(e)
{
  var myemail = "myemail";
  var email = "";
  var subject = "Re: "; 
  var message = "Thanks!";
try {  
  for(var field in e.namedValues) {
    message += field + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
    if (field == 'Subject') {
      subject += e.namedValues[field].toString();
    }
    if (field == 'Email') {
      email = e.namedValues[field].toString();
    }
  }   


  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo:myemail});
} catch(e){
    MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in Auto replying to contact form submission. No reply was sent.", e.message);
  }
}
```

I connected  this function to the submit button. However when I press the the submit button I get an e-mail saying:

`Failed to send e-mail: no recipient`

How do I fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you verified that `email` actually contains an email address?

Comment: @JSuar Yes the email field does contain an email.

Comment: Have you tried explicit parameter values to be sure the function is working for you? Example: `MailApp.sendEmail('yourEmail@example.com', 'Test Email', 'This is a test email.', {replyTo: 'anotherEmail@example.com'})`

Comment: @JSuar Have any idea why?

Comment: Possibly try `e.namedValues['Email']` explicitly in the MailApp function: `MailApp.sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email'], ...` Or try `e.namedValues[field].toString();` without the `.toString();`.

Comment: @JSuar Both ways did not work :( Any chance e is nil?

Comment: I think it is. I'm able to replicate the issues you're encountering. Not sure why `e` doesn't contain any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are make a few confusions about variables. `field` is an integer that you use as an index so a condition like `if (field == 'Email')` can never be true.

You have to get the key values from the form response object and use that to select values.

The other answer shows a possible way to achieve that by reading the spreadsheet but there is a more simple and direct way to do it directly from the object.

```
  for(var k in e.namedValues){ keys.push(k) };
  Logger.log("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys);
```

Then you can use that to check every response element. Returned values from text questions are string so you don't need to use `toString()`.

The full code is shown below:

```
function formSubmit(e){
  var keys = [];
  var email = '';
  var subject = '';
  var message = '';
  var myemail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  for(var k in e.namedValues){
    keys.push(k);
  }
  Logger.log("total " + keys.length + " keys: " + keys); 
  for(var field in keys) {
    message += field + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[keys[field]] + "\n\n";
    if (keys[field] == 'Subject') {
      subject += e.namedValues[keys[field]];
    }
    if (keys[field] == 'Email') {
      email = e.namedValues[keys[field]];
    }
  }   
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo:myemail});
}
```

btw, you don't need to hardcode your email address since GS has a method for it, the `onFormSubmit` trigger being an installable trigger it runs as you and you can use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`.

Answer (score 3):

See the links below for workarounds.

- http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/
- [setting up script to include google docs form data in email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683060/setting-up-script-to-include-google-docs-form-data-in-email-notification)

Example workaround code:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

// Credit to Henrique Abreu for fixing the sort order
for(var i in headers) {
    if (headers[i] = "Name") {
      name = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();
    }
    if (headers[i] = "Email") {
      email = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();
    }
    if (headers[i] = "Subject") {
      subject = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();
    }
    if (headers[i] = "Message") {
      message = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();
    }
}
```